# How to set automount permissions?

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, automount, raspberrypi

As I can see, on Ubuntu the default automount permissions for exFAT is 700.
I know I can set it manually in fstab but then it will not work for all exFAT usb drives I use (only for the ones I put in fstab).

Not only exFAT but normal FAT fs also is mounted with 700 permissions.

Is there any other way to change this permission setting to anything other than 700 than editing fstab?

mount:

```
/dev/sda1 on /media/pi/tempP1 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

ls -l (inside mount point):

```
    1 drwx------  1 pi   pi   131072 sty  1  1970 ./
63425 drwxr-xr-x+ 4 root root   4096 gru  1 10:41 ../
   11 drwx------  1 pi   pi   131072 lis 30 19:38 A/
    7 drwx------  1 pi   pi   131072 lis 30 08:48 B/
   12 drwx------  1 pi   pi   131072 lis 30 20:48 C/
   10 drwx------  1 pi   pi   131072 lis 30 19:16 D/
```

Comment: Please, show (ls -l) device permissions and directory permissions after mount.

Comment: Create a `udev rule` to get it to work for all `exFAT` fs! And `permissions` are we talking here?